# Ajax post call not working after server 301 redirection

Tags: jquery, liferay, redirect

We have recently used server redirection for home page URL.Now,upon making an ajax post call to the server,it responds with a 301 code and subsequently an ajax get request is sent,which does retrieve any response.We are using jQuery for making the Ajax call.
This problem only exists from home page,on whose URL,redirection has been implemented.
[image]

Comment: Can you add some code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your server-side redirection hits more than intended. The first option is to only redirect on GET instead of POST - see if this is sufficient.

If it isn't, you'll have to take care of other URLs - e.g. you might need to identify parameters identifying resource-requests (e.g. Ajax) and omit them from the redirection instruction as well. Maybe it's simplest to just redirect `^/home$` to `/`

Note that Portlet Action URLs as well as Portlet Render URLs and Resource URLs will point to the page a portlet is placed on.

Also, it might help to see your redirection instructions as well as the problem that you'd like to solve.